# filtering pandas dataframe rows by applying a function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that has about 5 columns. One columns values are wrong strings.

> e.g. abspodfahoidf

I have written a function to validate if this is a valid string (some characters are not allowed in the string).

Is there anyway that I can apply that function I created to all column values in the dataframe and drop all rows that are invalid? Dtype for this is shown as `object` when I do `pd.info()` on the dataframe.

Comment: Assuming your function `fn` returns boolean, you just need `df = df[df["Column"].apply(fn)]`

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example? What does your function do? Can you vectorize it?

Comment: @not_speshal this is what I wanted. If you can add an answer I can accept. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your function (called `fn` for example) returns a boolean value (i.e. `True`/`False`), you need:

```
df = df[df["Column"].apply(fn)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is how you can implement it.

```
def myfunction_ex():
# Your function definition with a return variable

for i in df.columns:
  df[i] = df[i].apply(lambda x: def(x))
```

Comment: `def` is a keyword

Answer (score 0):

import pandas as pd

mask=~(df["a"].str.contains("abc"))

df[mask]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).